# Grails 1.3.7 Error executing script War: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be found

Tags: java, grails, groovy, sax, jaxp

My problem is that every grails command I issue, even just `grails help` results in a `javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError`. I would like to use the JVM system property -`Djaxp.debug=1` (as documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html)) to troubleshoot how the `SAXParserFactoryImpl` is being looked for. However adding the directive as such: `grails -Djaxp.debug=1 help` produces no extra debugging information.

Is there an extra step required to get the jaxp debugging statements from a grails command line? Is there another way to discover why I am getting this error?

Here is the full stack trace of the error I am getting:

```
Error executing script War: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be found
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be found
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.doParse(XmlSettingsParser.java:160)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.parse(XmlSettingsParser.java:150)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings.load(IvySettings.java:412)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings.loadDefault(IvySettings.java:440)
        at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.configureDefault(Ivy.java:433)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.IvyContext.getDefaultIvy(IvyContext.java:201)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.IvyContext.getIvy(IvyContext.java:179)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.IvyContext.getSettings(IvyContext.java:215)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.module.status.StatusManager.getCurrent(StatusManager.java:42)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.module.descriptor.DefaultModuleDescriptor.<init>(DefaultModuleDescriptor.java:198)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.module.descriptor.DefaultModuleDescriptor.newDefaultInstance(DefaultModuleDescriptor.java:103)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.module.descriptor.DefaultModuleDescriptor.newDefaultInstance(DefaultModuleDescriptor.java:63)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.AbstractIvyDependencyManager.createModuleDescriptor(AbstractIvyDependencyManager.java:249)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.AbstractIvyDependencyManager$createModuleDescriptor.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.IvyDependencyManager.parseDependencies(IvyDependencyManager.groovy:602)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.DependencyDefinitionParser$parseDependencies.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.configureDependencyManager(BuildSettings.groovy:776)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings$configureDependencyManager.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.postLoadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:682)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:266)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:671)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings$loadConfig$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:653)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings$loadConfig.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:630)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:284)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:135)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
Error executing script War: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be found
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some months ago I had the same problem.
It turns out that I had another SAXParser* library in my app. For me it was a newer GPars library. So I removed it and it worked again.
I do not really know, if there is a possibility to use both implementations at the same time....

Comment: Well, I did find a SAXParserFactoryImpl that was polluting my classpath, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks. In my case I had `xml-apis` library on a classpath, which caused this error ([this suggestion](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-41515?focusedCommentId=285582&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-285582) helped me).